# Connected subset of $\Bbb R^2$ that disconnects with countable points removed.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, connectedness

I am asked to find a subset $A$ of $\Bbb R^2$ with the following property:

$(1).$ $A$ is connected.

$(2).$ $A-F$ is connected if $F$ is finite.

$(3).$ $A-C$ is disconnected for some countably infinite subset $C\subset A$.

I am beginning this problem with an attempt of setting $A=\{(x,y):x\in\Bbb Q\text{ or }y\in\Bbb Q\}$.

I am guessing $A-\Bbb Q^2$ is disconnected.

In fact, intuitively $A-\Bbb Q^2$ is totally path-disconnected: there could be no path connecting any of the two distinct points in $A-\Bbb Q^2$. Can we deduce $A-\Bbb Q^2$ is disconnected from here?

Fun fact: such space is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ as removing countably many points in $\Bbb R^2$ doesn’t affect connectedness.

Comment: Watch out: connected does not imply path connected, so non-path-connected does not imply disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path connectedness argument doesn’t quite work, since as noted in the comments, a non-path connected space can still be connected.

However, your example of $A-\mathbb Q^2$ is still certainly disconnected, since it does not intersect the diagonal, so $\{x<y\}$ and $\{x>y\}$ form a separation.

##### Update

Regarding the other criterion that $A-F$ is connected for finite $F$, given any point $(p,q)$ with $p\in \mathbb Q$, you can connect to infinitely many points $(p,q’)$ where $q’\in\mathbb Q$ (since you can take any neighborhood of $(p,q)$ not intersecting $F$), so take some $q’$ where $(\mathbb R \times \{q’\})\cap F =\emptyset$, and then you can connect to every line $\{p’\}\times \mathbb R$ ($p’\in \mathbb Q$) not intersecting $F$.  Since such $p’$ may be chosen independently of $(p,q)$, $A-F$ is path connected, hence connected.

##### Remark

As Steven Clontz points out in the comments, you can show $A-\mathbb Q^2$ is totally disconnected without much trouble, since both the diagonal and the reverse diagonal $\{y=-x\}$ separate the space, and shifting either of these by any rational number either horizontally or vertically gives another separation, so given $(p_1,q_1)\neq (p_2,q_2)\in A-\mathbb Q^2$, you can shift either the diagonal by some rational number to separate the two points, unless the line joining them is parallel to the diagonal, in which case you can use the reverse diagonal instead.

Answer (score 6):

I feel you are overthinking it. Let me suggest a simpler example: draw a line $y=0$ on your plane, then throw away all non-integer points on the line. What remains is two open half-planes held together with countably many points. This thing is obviously connected and even path-connected, and will remain so if you remove finitely many points.

So it goes.

Comment: Nonetheless, the example they suggested originally is still a valid example, and has the stronger property that removing countably-many points results in a totally disconnected set.

Comment: Sure. So it does more than we need at the cost of more thinking, and that's what I call overthinking (in a good sense).